# What does a square bracketed type signate: `[< t ]` mean in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml, caqti

I have been playing around with Dream and Caqti in OCaml and I recently ran into a type signature I've never seen before:

```ml
  val handle_error : [< Caqti_error.t ] -> Dream.response t

  let handle_error e =
    print_endline (Caqti_error.show e); error_template |> Dream.html
```

What does the `[< ]` around the type `Caqti_error.t` mean? At first I thought it was some sort of weird Monadic or Wrapper type, but I'm not sure what it is, what it does, or why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a polymorphic variant type, see https://ocaml.org/manual/polyvariant.html for more details.

In brief, polymorphic variants are a structural version of ordinary variants. And a type like `` [< `A | `B] `` in

```ml
let f: [< `A | `B ] -> int = function
| `A -> 0
| `B -> 1
```

means that the function accepts at most the constructor  `` `A `` or `` `B `` as an argument. Moreover, since polymorphic variants are structural, one does not need to define the constructor `` `A `` or `` `B `` before starting to use them.

Moreover, the `caqti` library is using an inline type abbreviation to avoid repeating the set of allowed variants multiple time. A good example of such use case would be

```ml
type t = [ `A | `B ]
let switch : [< t ] -> [> t ] = function
| `A -> `B
| `B -> `A
```

In the example above, the type `[> t]` means that both `` `A `` and `` `B `` were explicitly presents, but more variants might be added later. For instance, the type of list `l`

```ml
let l = [ switch `B; `C ]
```

is `` [> t | `C ] ``.